# Extract tables from multiple files to Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have no experience with VBA as I usually use Matlab or sometimes Python, but it seems like it is the most useful tool for a project I have. Basically from a large number of Word files, I have to extract a table and put it into a single Excel file. 
From a YT tutorial, I already have the following basic code:

```
Sub CopyTable()
Application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook

Dim doc As Document
Dim tbl As Table
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Integer
Dim tblRange As Range

Set doc = ThisDocument

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Set tbl = doc.Tables(3)
With tbl
LastRow = .Rows.Count
LastColumn = .Columns.Count

Set tblRange = .Cell(1, 1).Range
tblRange.End = .Cell(LastRow, LastColumn).Range.End

tblRange.Copy

xlwb.Worksheets(1).Paste

End With

Set xlwb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

Set tblRange = Nothing
Set tbl = Nothing
Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

However what I now have to do is applying this code to a certain folder with multiple doc(x) files. I would like to have the table of each separate Word file in a separate sheet within the same Excel file. How can I make `xlwb.Worksheets(1).Paste` dynamic?
Also, would it be possible to first paste the file name of the Word file in the Excel sheet in the first cell and then copy the table next to it?

Any guidance to incorporate these editions would be highly appreciated.

ADDED:

Using the advice below I have started to code the script in Excel:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer

filelist = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported", MultiSelect:=True)

If IsArray(filelist) Then

For i = 1 To Len(filelist)
wdFileName = filelist(i)
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If
With .Tables(TableNo)
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Dir(wdFileName)
'Worksheets(Dir(wdFileName)).Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Dir(wdFileName)
Worksheets(Dir(wdFileName)).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With
wdDoc.Quit savechanges = False
Next i
Else
wdFileName = filelist
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName)
With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If
With .Tables(TableNo)
For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
Next iRow
End With
End With
End If


Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can now select multiple files and also have added a function which names the sheets with the filename. However the code does not run properly after copying the info from the first file. It seems like the for loop does not update properly as I get a message: "this sheet name already exists". Maybe I'm missing some VBA logic here with regards to loops and indexing.

Comment: I think you would need to do it the other way round. While this code exports from Word to Excel (code runs in Word) you would need to write a code to import in Excel from Word. So you would need in Excel VBA: ① A loop to loop through a folder and open up the docx files. ② Within that loop add a worksheet for each file and copy/paste the table.

Comment: It looks like that you have this code in a Word document. To start with, I would suggest that you do this in an excel file as you want all your data from multiple Word docs to a single excel file. I am struggling to explain this in a simpler term but, I would use more than 1 UDF for this. A main UDF that goes through the folder(s) and decide which file it needs to open. This UDF than calls a second UDF (much like what you have) which copies and pasts the tables in a new sheet in the same file where you have your code

Comment: @Pᴇʜ great minds and all of that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per PEH's and my comments earlier, here is an approach

Copy the below UDF in a module:

```
Sub LookForWordDocs()
    Dim sFoldPath As String: sFoldPath = "c:\temp\"     ' Change the path. Ensure that your have "\" at the end of your path
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject                    ' Requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference
    Dim oFile As file

    ' Loop to go through all files in specified folder
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFoldPath).Files

        ' Check if file is a word document. (Also added a check to ensure that we don't pick up a temp Word file)
        If (InStr(1, LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Path)), "doc", vbTextCompare) > 0) And _
                (InStr(1, oFile.Name, "~$") = 0) Then

            ' Call the UDF to copy from word document
            CopyTableFromWordDoc oFile

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Above UDF checks all files in your specified folder and passes `Word` documents to the below UDF:

```
Sub CopyTableFromWordDoc(ByVal oFile As file)
    Dim oWdApp As New Word.Application                      ' Requires "Microsoft Word .. Object Library" reference
    Dim oWdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oWdTable As Word.Table
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow$, lLastColumn$

    ' Code to copy table from word document to this workbook in a new worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook

        ' Add the worksheet and change the name to what file name is
        Set oWS = .Worksheets.Add
        oWS.Name = oFile.Name

        ' Open Word document
        Set oWdDoc = oWdApp.Documents.Open(oFile.Path)

        ' Set table to table 3 in the document
        Set oWdTable = oWdDoc.Tables(1)

        ' Copy the table to new worksheet
        oWdTable.Range.Copy
        oWS.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone

        ' Close the Word document
        oWdDoc.Close False

        ' Close word app
        oWdApp.Quit

    End With

End Sub
```

> **CopyTableFromWordDoc UDF is untested as I didn't have a word document to test it against**

If you then run **LookForWordDocs**, it will go through all files in specified folder and pass them into **CopyTableFromWordDoc** UDF (excluding any non `Word` documents and any temporary `Word` documents). **CopyTableFromWordDoc** adds a new worksheet in current workbook and renames the worksheet same as the file name. It then copies table(3) from word document to this new sheet

**Tip:** You could add code to remove any existing sheets before sheets are added to the workbook; this would protect you against attempting to name a worksheet with the same name as an existing worksheet

Comment: Thanks! I tried to run the code but got a compile error "Argument not optional' in the "oWdRange.End = oWdTable.Cell(lLastRow, lLastColumn).Range.End" line.

Comment: I created a word document with a table and tested the code this time. Copy the edited **CopyTableFromWordDoc** UDF to your module (deleting the older version) and give it a go (don't forget to change the table number)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Power Query to extract tabular data from each Word document in a folder. There's a great example here: http://www.excelandpowerbi.com/?p=201

Answer (score -2):

I agree with the other answers that this would be best done in excel vba.
I'd suggest something like 
filelist = application.getopenfilename with multiselect set to true, to get a list of files

Then loop over the list using for i = 0 to len(filelist) structure if you start with 1 worksheet each sheet will be named sheet i+1 which you can use to reference it and add content/rename it et.c and you can pull the file name from the list position.